# Why is Powershell Flattening my Array?

Tags: powershell

```
$arrays = @();
$array  = @();
$string = 'one|two|three';
$array  = ($string -split '\|');
$arrays += $array;
$arrays[0][0]
```

I expected `$arrays` to be a two dimensional array the first element of which would be a reference to `$array`. Thus, `$arrays[0][0]` would contain the string 'one'.

Instead PoSh seems to be flattening `$arrays` into a single list containing the elements 'one', 'two', and 'three'. This is true even if I put the `@()` array constructor around `$array` in my append operation.

Adding an additional element to my append gets me close, but then I'll have empty elements in `$arrays`:

```
$arrays = @();
$array  = @();
$string = 'one|two|three';
$array  = ($string -split '\|');
$arrays += $array, '';
$arrays[0][0]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Think of PowerShell's `+` operator with an array as the LHS as  *concatenating arrays***, i.e., appending the *individual elements of the RHS* to the LHS array<sup>[1]</sup>
:

```
# Note: , has higher precedence than +, so this is the same as: ((1, 2) + (3, 4)).Count
> (1, 2 + 3, 4).Count # Same as: (1, 2, 3, 4).Count
4
```

> even if I put the @() array constructor around $array

**It is `,` that is the array-construction operator.**

`@()` is the *array sub-expression operator* - its purpose is to ensure that the output from the enclosed command becomes an array *unless it already is one*.
In other words: Something like `@(1, 2)` is a *no-op*, because `1, 2` already *is* an array.

Therefore, as you've discovered, **using `,` to construct a *nested* array is the solution**:

```
> (1, 2 + , (3, 4)).Count
3
```

- `, (3, 4)` wraps array `3, 4` in a single-element array.
- `+` then adds each element of that array - the one and only element that is the wrapped `3, 4` array - to the LHS.

---

<sup>[1] Let's not forget that a .NET array is an *immutable* data structure,
 so what is really happening is that, behind the scenes, PowerShell constructs a *new* array.</sup>

Comment: These are extremely useful details. Thank you so much for explaining this. Understanding that `,` is actually the array-construction operator makes this seem less like PoSh is doing squirrely things behind the scenes.

Answer (score 2):

After some additional research I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463190/avoiding-agnostic-jagged-array-flattening-in-powershell). This is, apparently, done by design. Adding a comma prior to $array in my append operation fixes the problem:

```
$arrays = @();
$array  = @();
$string = 'one|two|three';
$array  = ($string -split '\|');
$arrays += ,$array;
$arrays[0][0]
```