# How to create nested array and to add array elements in it?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, powercli

Below i'm trying to create nested array and to add array elements to it like below

```
$nArr = @(@('1','3'), @('5','7','9'), @('2','4','6'))
```

And here is the script to get the above structure

```
 $integ = @(2,3,3)

$nArr = ,@()
$nArr1 = @()
foreach ($pd in $integ) {
    for($i=0;$i -lt $pd;$i = $i+1) {
    $uinput= Read-Host -Prompt "Assign the pod numbers for"
    Write-Output `n
    $nArr1 += [array]$uinput
    }
    $nArr += @($nArr1)
   }
```

Inputs I gave for `$uinput` is `1,3,5,7,9,2,4,6`

But the final structure I got through the above script is

```
$nArr = @('1','3','5','7','9','2','4','6')
```

Suggestions please!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Powershell Multidimensional Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397137/powershell-multidimensional-arrays)

Comment: which specific part clarifies my doubt

Comment: Related: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390782/jagged-powershell-array-is-losing-a-dimension-when-only-one-element-exists), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34698844/multidimensional-arrays-with-only-one-entry), [3](https://superuser.com/questions/414650/why-does-powershell-silently-convert-a-string-array-with-one-item-to-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

To force value(s) to be an array, add a comma to the front. The problem (and beauty) of powershell is it is going to try and unwrap those arrays implicitly. You can also collect the output of `foreach`, `Foreach-Object`, and `For` loops directly to a variable. Be sure not to output items with `Write-Output` that you don't intend to collect/work with - that's what `Write-Host` is for.

```
$integ = @(2,3,3)

$nArr = foreach ($pd in $integ)
{
    $nArr1 = for($i=0;$i -lt $pd;$i = $i+1) {
        Read-Host -Prompt "Assign the pod numbers for"
        Write-Host `n
    }
    ,$nArr1
}

$nArr | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host Object type: $_.gettype().BaseType.name
    Write-Host Member count: $_.count
    write-host Values: $_
}
```

Output

```
Object type: Array
Member count: 2
Values: 1 3
Object type: Array
Member count: 3
Values: 5 7 9
Object type: Array
Member count: 3
Values: 2 4 6
```

Comment: i'm not seeing Values its empty

Comment: Not sure how you managed that.  https://imgur.com/JIlAsuj

Comment: i executed it as a **.ps1** script in **ISE** https://imgur.com/BNy9F0K

Comment: **write-host Values: $_ | Out-Host** yet this execution produces empty values

Comment: Oh I see, you are assigning the read-host to variable, remove that.

Comment: Now it worked like a charm :) so now I have the nested array exactly like this? @(@('1','3'), @('5','7','9'), @('2','4','6'))

Comment: Yes but it's going to be difficult to see it like that in powershell. We already confirmed there are 3 elements in which the first has 2 values and the other two have 3 values.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224366/discussion-between-django-unchained-and-doug-maurer).